# Как создать мод для более старых версий майнкрафт. iIDEA

Tags: python, minecraft

Я хотел бы написать мод для minecraft 1.8.9 в InteliJ IDEA, но вне зависимости от моих версий JDK, в расширении minecfrat dev.. показывает для forge только возможные версии с 1.16.5 - 1.12.1. Как исправить?

Comment: Информация, которую вы указали, может быть устаревшей. Официальная документация Forge указывает, что для версии Minecraft 1.8.9 последняя доступная версия Forge - 1.8.9-11.15.1.2318-1.8.9.